# Transform value in Variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

in my df I have the count of the lines that return me the following value.

```
total_rows = df.count()
print(total_rows)

Valor    145
dtype: int64
```

I would like to transform this value into a variable so that it looks like this

```
total_rows = 145
print(total_rows)

145
```

so that I use a variable 145 in other parts of my code

How do I make this change?

Comment: `total_rows = df['Valor'].notnull().sum()` will achieve the same as counting the `'Valor'` column.

Comment: @ALollz Why'd you prefer that over `df.Valor.count()`?

Comment: @Neither I guess they're both equivalent, but I feel like `.notnull().sum()` is a bit more self-documenting as I often forget whether `count` or `size` is the one which ignores `NaN` (or at least leaves open that possibility)

Answer (score 0):

Slice the "Valor":

```
total_rows = df.count()['Valor']
```

Comment: seems wasteful to count many things but take out one thing only